# django exception: libperconaserverclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: django, python-2.7, mysql-python, web-frameworks

I am new to django.

I get this error when I update settings.py with database and run

```
$python2.7 manage.py migrate
```

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb
>   module: libperconaserverclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

Is it because of version of mysql ? if so which version should I use ?

```
 $ python2.7 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/sachints/project/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: libperconaserverclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am using RHEL 6.7, MySql Server version: 5.1.73 and  Python 2.7.11

Comment: If you have control over the machine, you might need to `yum install mysql-devel`.

Comment: @ShangWang  I have already installed it, `mysql-devel-5.1.73`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yum -y install mysql-devel
2. ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libperconaserverclient_r.so.18  /usr/lib
3. ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libperconaserverclient_r.so  /usr/lib
4. Idconifg
5. done!